# How to put text on image src tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have problem with my code (i'm still studying js).  I wanna put link from image to images src tag,  I don't know how to do this can you help me?

this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".img").click(function(){
        $("#img_link").text($(this).attr('src'));
        $('#myModal').modal('hide') ;
    });
});

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary hd" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">add img</button>
<img id="img_link" src=""/>
```

Comment: Please provide all of the relevant code and elaborate on what you are trying to do.

Comment: What is a “link from image”? Currently, your code just places the value of the `src` attribute somewhere and hides a modal, on click. How does that differ from your desired result?

Comment: What is the issue with your current code? What is the expected result?

Comment: Seeing your edited HTML, which element matches the selector `.img`? I don’t see one. `$("#img_link").text` makes no sense. Images don’t have text.

Comment: I wanna display image in <img src = "my link from .img" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".btn").click(function(){
$("#img").attr("src", "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/ab/b6/a8/abb6a800ab2193fcedd9bda566b7402c.jpg");
$("#img_link").text($("#img").attr('src'));
 //$('#myModal').modal('hide') ;
});
});
```

```html
<div class="img_content">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary hd" data-toggle="modal" data-    target="#myModal">add img</button> 
  <p id="img_link"></p>
  <img id="img" src=""/>
</div>
```

Comment: How is your answer different compare to the actual question ? Its the exact copy

Comment: Take a close look at my answer and question and see the difference!

Comment: No difference at all. OP has not provided all the information. I think you are only making assumption on what might be the case. you just replaced `.img` with `.btn` - What if OP has `.img` class. Please consider information in your answer on how this magically will work for the OP .

Comment: Take a close look at my answer again. Sometimes, quite a few adjustments in the code are enough for the answer. The author asked to put a link in the attribute of the img tag, and I demonstrated this to him.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov but sir yourcode snippet not working on button click?

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov tell me  sir why `<button> Tag` is not working on click?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use ,

`$("#img_link").attr('src', 'the text you want to go into src')`

As you did not provide all the code I think the text would be

`$(this).text()`

Comment: i got  my text (link) from .img but i dont know how can i put this text to img src =.

Comment: @istten, the author of the given answer is absolutely correct, and in the same way I made it known in my answer. In order to place your link on a picture in img, you need to register this link in an attribute like this - `$(selector).attr("src", "your_link");`